# Rails: Override CSS on button_to?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

In my view have this button:

```
<%= button_to 'YES', { :controller => 'pages', :action => 'yes', :id => p.id, remote: true}, {class: "yes_button"} %>
```

and in .css, I try to style the button with this:

```
.yes_button {
    color: white;
    background-color:#828282;
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', serif;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    padding:0px 6px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

But there seems to be some other styling applied to the button as well as the custom styling I have applied. Is there a way to remove all of the styling before I put my own styling on it? (Or fix it in another way)?

Comment: If you're in Chrome or Firefox, use the browser inspector to check the full styles active in one element in real time. Then you can easily see if there are other styles other than yours that are active on the button.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is Cascading Style Sheets, which means the rules later will overwrite the rules on same elements before.

Several ways to realize this

1. Put your style after original style. Done.
2. Name your style more specific. Say your original style is on `.button`, then for this style

   ```
   .button .yes_button { some rules }
   ```
3. Add `!important` after the rule if you really can't overwrite it. Caution is this is a bad practice, use it when you really have no other choice.

Answer (score 0):

`button_to` creates a form with a default `class` named `button_to` to change the name of this class and override the default css you can do this:

```
<%= button_to 'YES', { :controller => 'pages', :action => 'yes', :id => p.id, remote: true}, {form_class: "yes_button"} %>
```